Pyspark Filtering Array inside a Struct column
I have a column in my Spark DataFrame that has this schema:
root
 |-- my_feature_name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- first_profiles: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- storeId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- storeIdHashed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lastUpdated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sum1d: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- second_profile: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- storeId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- storeIdHashed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lastUpdated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sum1d: long (nullable = true)

I want to remove the lines in the most nested array where storeId = some value.
The closer I got to the solution is something like this F.expr("filter(my_feature_name.first_profiles.attributed, x -> x.storeId NOT IN (123124124))")
but that only sends me back the final array without the struct on top of it..
Thanks for the help.

Would you be able to upload some sample data for this schema? Just for learning purposes.

and expected output please.

You can define a function that filters all arrays in a map according to the storeId in the nested field:
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#This id is filtered out
id_to_filter_out = '12345'

#Filter on Store ID
def filter_function(map_data):
    for key in map_data:
        map_data[key] = [x for x in map_data[key] if x['storeId'] != id_to_filter_out]
    return map_data

#Define as UDF
filter_udf = udf(filter_function, MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("storeId", StringType(), True),
            StructField("storeIdHashed", StringType(), True),
            StructField("lastUpdated", LongType(), True),
            StructField("sum1d", LongType(), True)
        ])), True))

You can then apply the function to the maps and add the results to the struct 'my_feature_name':
df = df.withColumn("my_feature_name", 
                   struct([filter_udf(col("my_feature_name.first_profiles")).alias("first_profiles"),
                           filter_udf(col("my_feature_name.second_profile")).alias("second_profile")]))


This is how I solved it:
df = df.withColumn(
        "my_feature_name",
        F.col("my_feature_name").withField(
            first_profile,
            F.transform_values(
                "my_feature_name.first_profile",
                lambda key, value: F.filter(value, lambda _: ~_.storeId.isin(black_list)),
            ),
        ),
    )

